# How to integrate $\cos(x+a)\cos(x+a+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I'm doing a probability problem and need to integrate  $\cos(x+a)\cos(x+a+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Not sure how to deal with the $b$, as otherwise it would be quite straight forward. Sorry for lack of working, I have made no progress.

Comment: Hint: Use the addition formula for $\cos(z+b)=\cos z \cos b - \sin z \sin b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can perform substitution of $y=x+a$ which should leave you with the integral

$$\int \cos y \cos(y+b)dy$$

which is slightly simpler. Now, use addition formula for $\cos(y+b)$. This will result in a sum, so you need to calculate two integrals, but they are both fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use the linearisation formulae first:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x+a)\cos(x+a+b)&=\frac12(\cos\bigl((x+a)+(x+a+b)\bigr)+\cos\bigl((x+a)-(x+a+b)\bigr)\\[1ex]
&=\frac12(\cos\bigl(2x+2a+b)+\cos b).
\end{align*}
Then it is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\cos(x+a)\cos(x+b)dx=\int\frac{\cos(x+a)}{\cos(x+b)}\cdot\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x+a)}$$
$$=\left|\frac{\cos(x+a)}{\cos(x+b)}=t\Rightarrow\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x+a)}=\frac{dt}{\sin(b-a)}\right|$$
$$=\int t\cdot \frac{dt}{\sin(b-a)}=\frac{1}{\sin(b-a)}\int t dt=\frac{t^2}{2\sin(b-a)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2(x+a)}{2\sin(b-a)\cos^2(x+b)}+C$$